# Direction & Vector Based Calculus Problem?

Tags: calculus

Find a vector-valued function f that
parametrizes the curve in the direction indicated.

$4x^2 + 9y^2 = 36$  (a) Counterclockwise. (b) Clockwise

My first assumption as to solve this problem is that sin and cosine are involved. I assume that means that I rewrite the problem as $4cosx+ 9siny = 36.$ Then you divided it and get $1/9cosx+ 1/4siny= 1$. What I do not understand is how does direction effect how this problem is solved. I can see that this is a sphere clearly yet how does direction affect how a sphere is formed?

Comment: how did you get $4cosx + 9siny = 36$?. This is an equation of ellipse $\frac{x^2}{3^2} + \frac{y^2}{2^2} = 1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $f(t)=(3\cos(t),2\sin(t))$ for the clockwise, and $f(t)= (3\cos(t),-2\sin(t))$ for the other. In both cases $0\le t\le2\pi$.

Comment: why not plotting? http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=parametricplot+%283cos%28t%29%2C2sin%28t%29%29%2C%7Bt%2C0%2C%CF%80%2F2%7D

Comment: Why did you use those numbers and trig properties?

Comment: Any ellipse centered at the origin can be described by $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1$ so a little algebra with the trig functions works. You need also the identity $\cos(t)^2+\sin(t)^2=1$.

Comment: What about 3cos(t) and 2sin(t) where did the 3 and 2 come from?

Comment: You need to see that parameterizing means put $x,y$ in terms of a parameter, in our case, $x=3\cos(t)$ and $y=2\sin(t)$ so when you insert those expressions on $4x^2+9y^2$... what do you get?

Comment: $4(3cos(t))^2+ 9(2sint))^2= 36$

Comment: Right! there you are